# Navigate from one fragment to another fragment on click of a button

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is the code II implemented by googling and reading another stack overflow answers. but any answer is not working for me.

Following code this error - "No view found for id 0x7f09009e

Please help me to implement this

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

//////more code here //////

OnClickListener listner = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment=null;
                if(v==rootView.findViewById(R.id.Button)){
                    fragment = new SortListFragment();
                }
                FragmentManager manager =getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_sort, fragment);
                transaction.commit();


            }
        };

         ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
         btn.setOnClickListener(listner);

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Didn't  you try to handle the onClick event and the insertion of the new fragment in your activity class using an interface?

Comment: please provide layout file. it seems the id sortButton or button doesn't exists

Comment: inflate layout first. and use inflated view to find the layout views.(like imagebutton)

Comment: add your complete error log

Comment: Try to use `android.R.id.content` as your container in `transaction.replace`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ButtonOnClickInterface interface;
public void onCreateView(//parameters){
   View view=//inflate the view;
   Button button =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnclickListener{
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v){
           try{
              interface.onClick();
           }catch(Throwable e){
              //may be null
           }
       }
   });
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context c){
   super.onAttach(c);
   try{
      interface=(ButtonOnClickInterface)c;
   }catch(Throwable e){
      //not implemented
   }
}
```

And your interface

```
interface ButtonOnClickInteface{
   void onClick();
}
```

Implement this interface in your activity.

Comment: what is `myActivity` here

Comment: Sorry my bad. Updated the anwser.

Comment: Thanks helping a fellow sri lankan. but code isn't do any thing :(

Comment: Are you sure you did everything right? Make a log on the onClick() method implementation of your activity to see whether the method is really called.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line above on click listner:

```
rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.<your layout xml>, container,
                    false);
```

Comment: Remove this line  super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState); and check

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to provide layout file in which you have put buttons and all.

So please provide below line in your code after "**super.OnCreateView()**"

```
  rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_file, container, false);
```

And then check it is working or not, hope this will work

Comment: make sure layout passed is correct and buttons are in that layout only not in activity. Also check that in declaration you have wrote R.id.button (means small button) and in click listner you are comparing with R.id.Button (Capital "B"), so check it also.

Comment: If this is the case it would produce a null pointer exception.